# Web Application Scallability

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x, scalability

we have developed Web application using spring framework(Spring MVC) with Hibernate as an ORM.

Now we are focusing on application scalability. And finally we have derived the following idea

We have been planned to divide the application into smaller modules which is independent to other modules(ie. only Model Part from MVC). Then we planned to create several nodes in jboss then in each node we will deploy our modules(ie. Single module).

For Eg: In Node 1 Module A will be deployed and Node 2 Module B will be deployed and so on.And all the controllers will be deployed in one node.

So when request comes to one controller which will be running in one node, needs to identify the model which is running in other node.
can any one give us the idea how to achieve this.

Technologies used:
Spring Framework 
Hibernate
Jboss AS 7

Comment: IMHO, to scale web application in that way is wrong. The better way is deploy projects to all nodes, and configure a load balancer, because one of your modules ought to be a bottleneck of your architecture.

Comment: Agreed. It can work to some extent - like having a server dedicated for generating reports. Something that you might be able to manage with a job queue. But as described, to for example have one node be responsible for the model, that makes little sense.

Comment: Hi Bezzy, thanks for your opinion. The one thing which I forgot to mention here is  that , we planned to deploy the same module in more than one node . so if any bottleneck for one module the same module will be available in another node...